# Is there a way to set worker weight?

Tags: locust

I have two machine to do the load test. One machine has worse CPU performance. And the machine will reach high CPU usage when number of users keep increasing, while the other machine still has low CPU usage. Locust complains:

```
[2022-07-28 11:22:15,529] PF1YW96X-MUO/WARNING/root: CPU usage above 90%! This may constrain your throughput and may even give inconsistent response time measurements! See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html for how to distribute the load over multiple CPU cores or machines
[2022-07-28 11:25:06,766] PF1YW96X-MUO/WARNING/locust.runners: CPU usage was too high at some point during the test! See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-distributed.html for how to distribute the load over multiple CPU cores or machines
```

I want to set lower weight for the machine who has worse CPU perfomance. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run fewer worker processes on the weak machine. If necessary you could run more than one process per core on the strong machine, just to make it take more Users.